# $\Delta_1^1\stackrel{?}{=}FOL$

Tags: logic, computational-complexity

Let $\varphi$ be a sentence in second order logic that happens to be in $\Sigma_1^1\cap\Pi_1^1(=:\Delta_1^1)$. It is claimed, that $\varphi$ be equivalent to a sentence in first order logic. Is this true? If so, how does one show this?

---

**Update.** Thanks, Andreas. The approach with Interpolators works, now I can rest assured that $FOL=\Delta_{1}^{1}$.

Comment: Do you mean in the language of arithmetic? Do you mean in arbitrary languages, extended naturally to second-order logic? Do you mean... what? All the terms here can be interpreted in more than one way, and you've only vaguely given context sufficient for an answer.

Comment: @AsafKaragila The OP left a comment elsewhere: "Asaf, I cannot add a comment somehow, so I write here instead. I mean plain FOL and SOL. I do NOT mean arithmetic-hierarchy, just the plain old hierarchy of formulae based on quantifier-blocks in prenex normal form."

Comment: @Thomas, this is not the time or place to ask additional questions. If you want to ask a different question (e.g. the axiom of choice related one; then you should ask it in a separate thread). [Let me point out that you can find the answer in Jech - The Axiom of Choice, Ch. 9.]

Answer (score 4):

This is a consequence of Craig's Interpolation Lemma.  Suppose (to simplify notation) that the $\Sigma^1_1$ form of $\phi$ is $(\exists X)\,\alpha(X)$ and the $\Pi^1_1$ form is $(\forall Y)\,\beta(Y)$, where $\alpha(X)$ and $\beta(Y)$ are essentially first-order formulas except that they involve the second-order variables $X$ and $Y$, respectively.  (In general, there could be several $X$'s and several $Y$'s but that doesn't affect the idea, only the notation.)  Note that we could also consider $\alpha(X)$ and $\beta(Y)$ to be honest first-order sentences, in a vocabulary (= language = signature) that has $X$ and $Y$ as new predicate symbols.  The fact that $(\exists X)\,\alpha(X)$ implies $(\forall Y)\,\beta(Y)$ in second-order logic means exactly the same as saying that the implication $\alpha(X)\to\beta(Y)$ is valid in the sense of first-order logic.  Now Craig's Lemma provides a first-order formula $\theta$, in which neither $X$ nor $Y$ occurs, such that both $\alpha(X)\to\theta$ and $\theta\to\beta(Y)$ are valid.  Translating that information back to the framework of second-order logic, we find that $(\exists X)\,\alpha(X)$ logically implies $\theta$, which in turn logically implies $(\forall Y)\,\beta(Y)$.  But, by hypothesis, $(\exists X)\,\alpha(X)$ and $(\forall Y)\,\beta(Y)$ are logically equivalent (because they're both equivalent to the original $\phi$), and so $\theta$ is also equivalent to them.

Comment: Could you say something about the difference between being able to prove a $Δ^1_1$-formula (which would then be equivalent to an arithmetical formula) and arbitrary $Δ^1_1$-properties, since after all $Δ^1_1$-CA is strictly stronger than arithmetical comprehension? The asker's provocative title seems to completely miss that...

Comment: @user21820 The OP was using $\Delta^1_1$ to mean expressible in both existential second-order and universal second-order form in pure logic, not in the arithmetical or analytical hierarchies.

Comment: Ahh okay I see now. Sorry it just didn't occur to me that the asker was only talking about the pure logic. Thanks!